# Hide elasticsearch to outside network

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I am looking for a solution to a problem we are currently having with a security training. We would give our students access to Kibana. There they are expected to analyze data in Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch itself we would like to hide because we can't configure it securely with TLS for certain reasons.

In summary: Kibana should be able to access elasticsearch. But nothing else.

Does anyone know a simple solution for this without having to enable TLS? We are using docker-compose to set it up. I already thought about some kind of webVPN or similar.

Comment: If you run in docker compose and you don't expose the 9200 port of elasticsearch node must work?

Comment: If I don't expose the port, Kibana won't work.Or is there another way for this?

Comment: If Kibana is declare in the docker compose, is not necessary to expose elastic node, kibana must talk to the port (9200). Could you paste the docker file ?